# Is the callbacks in QuickFIX client guaranteed to be called?

Tags: quickfix

I have a QuickFIX initiator which receives frequent market data updates.
Altough i process each update as quickly as possible, still i have a concern regarding the callbacks.
Lets say, QuickFIX called my callback function and while i'm processing it, it's again called my function before the previous call is going on. What will happen in this situation? Is it guaranteed that i will be called for the next call or the engine can skip it because of the previous call is still going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the message is not malformed, then yes, a callback should be triggered for every message received.

(If it is malformed, the engine will reject automatically and will not pass the message to your application code.)

Incoming messages are actually collected in a queue while you are processing them.  For this reason, you should not perform time-intensive operations in the the callbacks.  If you have some lengthy processing, you should dispatch it to another thread so as to not cause the queue to back up.